# $\mathcal{O}$-module dual preserves equivariance

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This question was asked on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376637/mathcalo-module-dual-preserves-equivariance) but received no attention.

I'm under the impression that the $\mathcal{O}$-module dual preserves equivariance of an $\mathcal{O}$-module. I'm trying to write down a proof but couldn't find a straightforward one.

To be more precise, if $G$ is an (affine) algebraic group over $\mathbb C$ with an action on a variety $X$, I would like a simple proof that $(-)^\vee = \mathcal Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(-, \mathcal O_X)$ is a functor from the category of $G$-equivariant $\mathcal O_X$-modules to itself.

It seems a little tricky as pullback (which is involved in checking equivariance) does not work so well with $\mathcal Hom$.

So far I can only get a proof in the situation where $X$ is normal quasi-projective. In this situation we can take an equivariant resolution of an equivariant sheaf $\mathcal F$ by equivariant vector bundles $\mathcal E^\bullet$ (see [5.1.26, Chriss-Ginzburg] for example). This resolution works well with equivariant maps between sheaves $\mathcal F \to \mathcal G$. Since vector bundles play nicely with $\mathcal Hom$ and pullback, we can obtain equivariance of $\mathcal F^\vee$ by arguing with $\mathcal E^\bullet$. But this proof is a bit unsatisfying and relies on normality of $X$. This is what leads to my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pullback does commute with *flat* morphisms (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C6I), and every isomorphism is flat, so your claim should definitely be true without any additional assumptions on $X$.

Comment: @Jef thank you for your comment. But I'm not sure I follow -- how does this help with dealing with $\mathcal Hom$?

Comment: I think the relevant point is that the group scheme is flat over the base (automatic over a field). Then all the face maps in the simplicial scheme G^* × X are flat, so if E and F are G-equivariant O_X-modules (= cartesian sections of Mod_O over this simplicial diagram), so is Hom(E,F) by the Stacks project reference given by Jef.

Comment: @MarcHoyois thank you! I will think about this.